# combining multiple UNION inside a view in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-tuning

I want  to create a view as below.

```
Create view SomeView
AS
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(ID,'ID') as Id, 
ISNULL(ID,'unknown') + ':' + 'ID' AS label,
ISNULL(ID,'unknown') AS [value]
FROM [test].[emp].[OrgView]
  UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(EMP_ID,'ID') as Id, 
ISNULL(EMP_ID,'unknown') + ':' + 'EMP_ID' AS label,
ISNULL(EMP_ID,'unknown') AS [value]
FROM [test].[emp].[OrgView]
  UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(LICENSE_NO,'LICENSE_NO') as Id, 
ISNULL(LICENSE_NO,'unknown') + ':' + 'LICENSE_NO' AS label,
ISNULL(LICENSE_NO,'unknown') AS [value]
FROM [test].[emp].[OrgView]
.
.
.
.
.
10 such selects
```

So in this case, will a call be made for each select block or it will just one call ? **I do not want this to make 10 different calls for each select**. Please point me to some resource online if you know.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the previous rather similar question.  The OP could have been clearer on the differences, but this has additional customization beyond just the ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpivot using `APPLY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(v.ID, v.id_default) as Id, 
       COALESCE(o.FIRST_NAME, 'unknown') + ':' + v.name_suffix AS label,
       COALESCE(o.VALUE, 'unknown') AS [value]
FROM [test].[emp].[OrgView] o CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (o.ID, 'ID', 'Unknown'),
             (o.EMP_ID, 'ID', 'EMP'),
             (o.LICENSE, 'LICENSE_NO', 'LICENSE_NO'), . . . 
     ) v(ID, id_default, name_suffix);
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. Sorry but I had to edit the questions/query a bit. Can you please help me now.

Comment: @Naxi . . . I see the difference.